# How to execute POST using CURL

Tags: post, curl, asp-classic

How to execute `POST` using `CURL`, i have this basic .asp that receives the data via `POST` and show the result in `.JSON` format.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Response.Write("{ ""responseCode"": " + Request("responseCode") + ", ""publication_id"": " + Request("publication_id") + ", ""version"": " + Request("version") + "}")  
%>
```

Comment: I was wondering the reason for the -1!

Comment: any explanation for the -1 ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from a basic search i found how to do this:

$**curl** --data "**responseCode**=jorgesys&**publication_id**=magaz234rewK&**version**=1.0" http://mywebsite.com/appiphone/android/newsstand/psv/curl/posted.asp

then i have as a result:

```
{ 
  "responseCode": jorgesys, 
  "publication_id": magaz234rewK, 
  "version": 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just passing one of the parameters below will make it a POST request.

```
$ curl --help | grep POST
-d, --data DATA     HTTP POST data (H)
    --data-ascii DATA  HTTP POST ASCII data (H)
    --data-binary DATA  HTTP POST binary data (H)
    --data-urlencode DATA  HTTP POST data url encoded (H)
```